# Select and pivot_wider simultaneously

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to modify the dataframe below to include two new columns: one for positive oxygen content, one for negative oxygen content, based on the either "+" or "-" element in the Oxygen column. Below is my code:

```
df2 <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = Oxygen, values_from = concentration)
```

However, the end result only shows NAs for the -Oxygen column. What went wrong?

Libraries used included tidyverse.

Below is my dataframe:

```
structure(list(Sample = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 43, 46, 47, 83, 84, 
86, 87, 125, 126, 127, 129, 165, 167, 168, 169, 170, 206, 207, 
209, 210, 211, 247, 248, 249, 251, 252, 288, 289, 290, 291, 293, 
329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 411, 412, 
413, 414, 415, 416, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 493, 494, 495, 
497, 498, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 
580, 616, 618, 619, 620, 621, 657, 658, 659, 660, 662, 698, 699, 
700, 701, 702, 703, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 780, 781, 782, 
783, 784, 785, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 862, 863, 864, 865, 
866, 867, 905, 906, 907, 908, 944, 945, 947, 948, 985, 986, 987, 
988, 990, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1029, 1030, 1031, 1067, 1068, 1069, 
1070, 1071, 1072, 1108, 1109, 1110, 1111, 1112, 1113, 1149, 1150, 
1151, 1152, 1153, 1154, 1190, 1192, 1193, 1194, 1195, 1231, 1232, 
1233, 1234, 1236, 1272, 1273, 1274, 1275, 1276, 1277, 1313, 1314, 
1315, 1316, 1317, 1318, 1354, 1355, 1357, 1358, 1359, 1395, 1396, 
1397, 1398, 1399, 1400, 1436, 1437, 1438, 1439, 1440, 1441, 1477, 
1478, 1479, 1480, 1481, 1482, 1518, 1519, 1520, 1521, 1522, 1523, 
1559, 1560, 1561, 1562, 1563, 1564, 1600, 1601, 1602, 1603, 1604, 
1605, 1641, 1642, 1643, 1644, 1645, 1646, 1682, 1683, 1684, 1685, 
1686, 1687, 1723, 1724, 1725, 1726, 1727, 1728, 1764, 1767, 1768, 
1769, 1806, 1807, 1846, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1887, 1888, 1890, 1891, 
1892, 1928, 1929, 1930, 1932, 1933, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1974, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2051, 2052, 2053, 2054, 2055, 2056, 
2092, 2093, 2094, 2095, 2096, 2097, 2133, 2134, 2135, 2136, 2137, 
2138, 2174, 2175, 2176, 2177, 2178, 2179, 2215, 2217, 2218, 2219, 
2220, 2256, 2257, 2258, 2259, 2260, 2297, 2298, 2299, 2300, 2301, 
2302, 2338, 2340, 2341, 2342, 2343, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2382, 2384, 
2420, 2421, 2422, 2423, 2424, 2425, 2461, 2462, 2463, 2464, 2465, 
2466, 2502, 2503, 2504, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2543, 2544, 2545, 2546, 
2547, 2548, 2584, 2585, 2586, 2587, 2588, 2589), Drug = c("Ab1", 
"Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab2", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", 
"Ab2", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab3", 
"Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", 
"Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", 
"Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", 
"Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab5", 
"Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", 
"Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", 
"Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", 
"Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", 
"Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab3", 
"Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab1", "Ab2", 
"Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", 
"Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", 
"Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", 
"Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", 
"Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", 
"Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", 
"Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab1", "Ab3", "Ab4", 
"Ab5", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", 
"Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", 
"Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", 
"Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", 
"Ab1", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", 
"Ab5", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab3", 
"Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab6", "Ab1", 
"Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", 
"Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", 
"Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", "Ab5", "Ab6", "Ab1", "Ab2", "Ab3", "Ab4", 
"Ab5", "Ab6"), concentration = c(538, 40, 7300, 530, 127, 230, 
50, 140, 215, 440, 50, 540, 120, 3850, 12340, 5090, 3190, 610, 
6360, 520, 140, 190, 500, 30, 460, 120, 190, 350, 30, 6070, 50, 
150, 370, 40, 6670, 440, 220, 3820, 3860, 11960, 5350, 2000, 
2570, 1670, 11390, 3950, 1170, 810, 3240, 2610, 11840, 4400, 
1580, 1900, 320, 30, 6150, 300, 110, 150, 2560, 1660, 11910, 
1120, 870, 3830, 3610, 12320, 5440, 2040, 2860, 2810, 1840, 11250, 
2730, 1040, 1080, 3430, 12440, 5160, 1770, 2230, 400, 90, 3480, 
230, 90, 490, 120, 3230, 270, 170, 110, 550, 150, 3570, 330, 
190, 120, 430, 110, 3010, 240, 150, 130, 690, 120, 4050, 270, 
200, 130, 660, 80, 3530, 220, 160, 80, 3530, 260, 170, 110, 680, 
70, 220, 160, 1240, 1430, 3800, 4700, 990, 560, 460, 2770, 3500, 
310, 330, 1120, 1230, 3000, 5000, 720, 890, 910, 860, 2930, 4540, 
480, 590, 1410, 1550, 3990, 5140, 900, 1170, 1710, 4060, 5440, 
1120, 1290, 690, 780, 2830, 3390, 470, 1650, 1820, 4220, 5430, 
990, 1470, 2630, 530, 4050, 580, 350, 380, 1230, 120, 280, 120, 
110, 1860, 700, 3720, 700, 440, 500, 1290, 230, 4020, 300, 170, 
140, 2920, 640, 4650, 690, 380, 390, 1790, 880, 4320, 830, 530, 
620, 970, 200, 3740, 310, 190, 120, 2880, 700, 4080, 760, 470, 
520, 1450, 90, 5310, 920, 150, 140, 1360, 60, 5190, 800, 130, 
120, 1370, 100, 5100, 1040, 140, 140, 1250, 770, 130, 110, 130, 
5430, 1710, 5530, 1100, 170, 1390, 110, 1070, 160, 140, 1540, 
100, 5720, 170, 170, 1260, 30, 4140, 260, 40, 710, 20, 3530, 
220, 80, 1000, 40, 3720, 210, 80, 50, 610, 30, 3710, 180, 60, 
50, 2030, 30, 3820, 240, 70, 60, 720, 20, 3590, 180, 80, 50, 
820, 3710, 160, 70, 50, 660, 20, 3450, 160, 60, 310, 80, 4910, 
370, 130, 80, 230, 3830, 260, 120, 90, 230, 100, 3910, 410, 120, 
190, 60, 4210, 240, 100, 80, 320, 70, 4220, 330, 120, 60, 220, 
80, 3910, 320, 120, 110, 220, 50, 3830, 260, 100, 80, 20, 10, 
40, 10, 10, 10), Oxygen = c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"
), Donor = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
"D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
"D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
"D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", 
"D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", 
"D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", 
"D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", 
"D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", 
"D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D5", "D5", "D5", 
"D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", 
"D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", 
"D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", 
"D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", "D5", 
"D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", 
"D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", 
"D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", 
"D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D6", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", 
"D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", 
"D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", 
"D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", 
"D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D7", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", 
"D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", 
"D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", 
"D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", 
"D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8", "D8"), Illness = c("pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", 
"lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", 
"gastro", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", 
"lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", 
"gastro", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", 
"lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", 
"gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", 
"lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", 
"gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", 
"lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "gastro", 
"gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", 
"TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", 
"gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", 
"lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", 
"TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", 
"TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", 
"lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", 
"gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", 
"lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "gastro", 
"gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", 
"TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", 
"TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "gastro", 
"gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", 
"TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "TB", 
"TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", 
"TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", 
"lyme", "lyme", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", "pneumonia", 
"pneumonia", "pneumonia", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", "gastro", 
"gastro", "gastro", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "TB", "lyme", 
"lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme", "lyme")), row.names = c(NA, -345L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: There is no row where `Sample == 1` and `Oxygen == "-"`, so there is an `NA` value there. I think what you want is to remove the `Sample` column. For example, `pivot_wider(select(df, -Sample), names_from = Oxygen, values_from = concentration)
`

Comment: If you share the expected output, it would be easier to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sample` column is your problem, since each sample is a single combination of `Drug`, `Donor`, `Illness`, `concentration`, and `Oxygen` (+ or -). The first - value of `Oxygen` occurs at Sample 165. Your attempt will have several rows of `NA` for the `-` column because of this until you hit Sample 165 (which will have the `NA` value for the `+` column).

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Oxygen == "-")
# A tibble: 170 x 6
   Sample Drug  concentration Oxygen Donor Illness  
    <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    
 1    165 Ab1             610 -      D1    pneumonia
 2    167 Ab3            6360 -      D1    pneumonia
 3    168 Ab4             520 -      D1    pneumonia
 4    169 Ab5             140 -      D1    pneumonia
 5    170 Ab6             190 -      D1    pneumonia
 6    206 Ab1             500 -      D1    gastro   
 7    207 Ab2              30 -      D1    gastro   
 8    209 Ab4             460 -      D1    gastro   
 9    210 Ab5             120 -      D1    gastro   
10    211 Ab6             190 -      D1    gastro   
# ... with 160 more rows
```

Removing the `Sample` column as Bas suggested in the comments resolves this issue, but I cannot tell from the question if this is what you want. If you need the Sample ID in the transformed data, then we need to see more about what your desired output looks like.

```
pivot_wider(select(df, -Sample), names_from = Oxygen, values_from = concentration)
# A tibble: 190 x 5
   Drug  Donor Illness     `+`   `-`
   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Ab1   D1    pneumonia   538   610
 2 Ab2   D1    pneumonia    40    NA
 3 Ab3   D1    pneumonia  7300  6360
 4 Ab4   D1    pneumonia   530   520
 5 Ab5   D1    pneumonia   127   140
 6 Ab6   D1    pneumonia   230   190
 7 Ab2   D1    gastro       50    30
 8 Ab5   D1    gastro      140   120
 9 Ab6   D1    gastro      215   190
10 Ab1   D1    TB          440   350
# ... with 180 more rows
```

Comment: That was so much more simple than I thought. I was way overthinking this! Thanks for the help!